# Why is Shiv Puran called Tamasic?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, padma-purana, tamasic

Lord Shiva, in the Padma Purana (Uttara Khand 236.19–21, 18) describes which Puranas belong to which mode:

"O beautiful one, the Vishnu Purana, the Narada Purana, the auspicious Bhagavata Purana, and the Garuda, Padma, and Varaha Puranas all belong to the mode of goodness. They are all considered auspicious. Know that the Brahmanda, Brahma-vaivarta, Markandeya, Bhavishya, Vamana, and Brahma Puranas belong to the mode of passion. And know that these six Puranas belong to the mode of ignorance: the Matsya, Kurma, Linga, Shiva, Skanda, and Agni Puranas."

As I understand it, Bramha-Vishnu-Mahesh are above all three guna, it is just that they are the presiding deities of a particular guna. Shiva presides over Tamas guna, this doesn't mean Shiva himself is Tamasic (duh) but he can help his devotees to conquer/destroy their tamasic qualities. Praying to destroy/conquer/defeat absolutely anything falls under tamas, even the tamasic qualities. Shiva helps here.

But how does this correlate to an entire puran dedicated to him being in the mode of ignorance (tamas)? Does it mean that reading/reciting this book helps to destroy one's negative qualities?

The very first Shiv Puran chapter seems like so, a man called Devaraj is destined to go to hell because he's an immoral person but just by chance happens to listen Shiv Puran from a Guru. When Yamraj's men arrive to take to him to Yamlok (hell) they are intercepted by Shiva's men hence Devaraj reaches Shivlok (heaven).

Bibek Debroy writes that this classification is tenuous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: 
 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7984

Comment: @estimator the answers over there aren't very satisfactory.

Comment: Purana classification itself is a self contradictory concept as various Puranas have various opinions of what constitutes satvik, Rajasika and tamasic. You may read this -https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58083/34062

Comment: This as well - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58348/34062

Comment: @estimator Those verses are not found in the khanda version of the Skanda Purana. They are found in the Samhitā version which is a different recension compared to the Khanda one

Comment: Regarding the mātri samhita it is listed as a part of the Shivapurana in it's beginning itself but the recension which the translated version publishes does not contain it. It's published by some of the Bengali and southern recensions of the shiva purana but again doesn't seem to be available on the internet

Comment: You may see the Skandapurāna verses from this post -https://jagatgurublog.wordpress.com/2021/12/25/clarification-on-the-skanda-purana-verses-and-further-insights/

Comment: @estimator It's different. As there is not even a complete version published anywhere on the internet but fragmentary khanda-by-khanda portions that too with no translation, there are obviously going to be no explanations. Regardless, the famous Suta samhita is  from this samhita version of skanda purana only and is commented upon by the Advaitin Acharya Vidyaranya as well. So from a traditionalist perspective, it's accepted as authentic.

Comment: @estimator I am aware of that, I mentioned that Suta samhita only because it is a part of this samhitatmaka skandapurana alone since you asked about details of this version's manuscript and so on. Regarding The quotes from shankara samhita, they too have been cited by the Shaivacharya sripati pandita, albeit for the sake of it's rejection only.

Comment: In his brahmasutra bhasya @estimator.

Comment: I don't recollect the sutra number right now. Will re-check and post when i get it. @estimator.

Comment: @Black Cool. Many thanks!